# C++ setw problem. The output is not align and its is shifted a few space why is that?

Tags: c++

The code I'm using:

```
cout<<setw(70)<<left<<"\n\n1. Monthly salary";
cout<<": RM";
cin>> monthsal;

cout<<"2. Any KWSP deduction?\n";
cout<<setw(70)<<left<<"   Type 'Y' for Yes and 'N' for No";
cout<<": ";
cin>>kwsp;
```

Desired output:

```
1. Monthly salary                          : RM3200
2. Any KWSP deduction?
  Type 'Y' for Yes and 'N' for No          : Y
```

(Aligned on the colons.)

My code's output:

```
1. Monthly salary                        : RM3200
2. Any KWSP deduction?
  Type 'Y' for Yes and 'N' for No          : Y
```

How do I get my output to align correctly?

Comment: I still can't tell how you want this to be aligned. Do you want both "1. Monthly salary" _and_ "2. Any KWSP deduction?" to be on the same line, but with user input in between them?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a bit new and the output needs to be aligned. The colons needs to be aligned. I'm sorry if it's a bit confusing cause I'm still new to coding and this.

Comment: You'll need to use a monospace font.

Comment: It looks like the leading newlines in `"\n\n1. Monthly salary"` are messing up the width setting. Try printing those separately from the width formatting directives.

Comment: i just added some picture as reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
cout<<setw(70)<<left<<"\n1. Monthly salary";
cout<<": RM";
cin>> monthsal;
cout<<"2. Any KWSP deduction?";
cout<<setw(70)<<left<<"\n   Type 'Y' for Yes and 'N' for No";
cout<<": ";
cin>>kwsp;
```

Comment: I think removing the `\n\n` from the top, or at least printing it before the `setw` instead of as part of it, would be better.

Comment: I rearranged. I think it worked this time :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider: `cout << setw(5) << left << "\n\nOK!" << "Hi";`, `"\n\nOK!"` actually already consumed all 5 spaces that was set from `setw(5)`, because despite `'\n'` are not printed like a single width character, they still consumes one space. So this will actually print like:

```
OK!Hi    <-- notice no spaces between `OK!` and `Hi`
```

Now back to your case, if you have actually counted the character in the same line as `"1. Monthly salary"`, you will notice the first block is actually less than 70 character for the same reason.

To fix it, you will want to print the `"\n\n"` before your `setw`:

```
cout << "\n\n";
cout << setw(70) << left << "1. Monthly salary";
 ⋮
```

---

For similar reason, `'\t'` could also mess up your formatting, because the tab symbol is also considered a single character.

Comment: Thank you so much I finally did it :D